# Safely truncating a string in C# that may be `null`

Tags: c#

I have the following method but it fails if the string is null. How could I make it just return a null if the string is null?

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxChars)
{
    return value.Length <= maxChars ?
           value :
           value.Substring(0, maxChars) + " ..";
}
```

Could someone also explain to me what the "this" is there for. Sorry I'm not so good at C# and this is not my code.

Comment: Are you asking how to add an `if` statement and a second `return`? Really?

Comment: Turn your last sentence almost directly into code.

Comment: Where is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I think your need to `Substring(0, maxChars - 3)`. Otherwise, this `Truncate` routine may actually increase the string's length.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By checking for null and returning appropriately :)

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxChars)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return value.Length <= maxChars ?
           value : value.Substring(0, maxChars) + " ..";
}
```

Or you could even use another conditional:

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxChars)
{
    return value == null ? null
        : value.Length <= maxChars ? value 
        : value.Substring(0, maxChars) + " ..";
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` here? I tend not to question the Skeetmeister, but it does seem like it would be preferable.

Comment: @Polynomial that would violate the spec. The OP wants to return `null` if the parameter is `null`, but most likely he wants `""` if the parameter is empty. In my experience treating `""` and `null` as equivalent is very rarely good design.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Ah yes, I missed that point. In that case the code is perfect as it is. Move along! :)

Comment: I am a bit confused as it's not my code. Can you explain what the "this" is for ?

Comment: @Melissa: It makes it an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) - it means you'd be able to call it as `someString.Truncate(10)` - it makes a static method *seem* like an instance method on another type (string in this case).

Comment: Thanks Jon for the great example and explanation.

Comment: `return (value == null || value.Length < maxChars) ? value : value.Substring(0,maxChars) + " ..";`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jon Skeet's good anwer you wanted to know what the `this` is for. This makes this method an *extension method*. You *extend* the functionality of the string class with your specific function. `this string value` is the magic for Visual Studio to show you this function in the context menu for every string variable and for the compiler to give the variable, the method is called on as the first parameter to it. The function has to be static.

Answer (score -9):

Put a try catch block. If it triggers, return null.

Comment: No, that's *not* the idiomatic way of handling entirely avoidable exceptions in C#. It's simpler, more efficient, and more readable to explicitly check for null.

Comment: Exceptions should only be caught in exceptional circumstances. If you can check for an input that could cause an exception, you must do so.